# Matlab - Reading and writing the same video results in a bigger size file

Tags: matlab, video

I am trying to read and write the same video using the following code:

```
video = VideoReader('test.mp4');
videoOutput = VideoWriter('testOutput.mp4', 'MPEG-4');
open(videoOutput);

while hasFrame(video)
    writeVideo(videoOutput, readFrame(video, 'native'));
end

close(videoOutput);
```

However, `testOutput.mp4` is almost double in size. For example:

> Input video file size: 5.01 MB
>   Output video file size: 8.15 MB

I use `MPEG-4` on `VideoWriter` because input video is `H264 - MPEG4 (Part 10)` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the `Quality` property of the [`VideoWriter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-object.html) object -

> Video quality, specified as an integer in the range, [0,100]. Higher quality numbers result in higher video quality and larger file sizes. Lower quality numbers result in lower video quality and smaller file sizes.

Comment: Well the default value is 75. I changed it to 50 and file size is still 8.15 MB